# Does excessive humidity affect the ability to play pianissimo? (On the piano)

Tags: piano, dynamics

I have trouble playing pianissimo but ff produces a good tone. Could humidity have caused this?

Comment: There is information you could add here that will help you get a good answer. For example, could you play pianissimo before? And what kind of problem are you having now: pianissimo is too loud? Doesn't make any sound at all? The keys feel different? More detail will go a long way.

Comment: And especially where your piano is in the world. Others may be in similar climates, and would have first hand experience to share.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, humidity can affect keys but I suspect your question is deeper than that.

Dynamics come from the speed at which you strike the key.  If you are having problems playing softly, you are not feeling the weight of your arms nor the pull and your arms resistance to gravity.

Play a chord and very slowly play down into the keys from the hinge of your elbow.  Experiment with different speeds to find the even pianissimo sound you desire. Try to play to the point of sound.  That is the little bump you feel when you very slowly depress a key and not make a sound.  You will feel that bump, then with additional pressure, it will give way and you will hit the key bed without making a sound.  Never press into the key bed.  Pressing only produces tension and you can't raise your hand back up because you are pressing down.  You can't move in two directions at the same time.  It is simple physics.  Every motion must have an opposite motion.

Note also when you play that quiet chord, you are not using your fingers but playing from the arm.  Each finger should come from that same source combined with in/out, up/down, rotations, groupings and gravity.   Grouping, rotation and gravity will give you that quiet sound you desire.

Answer (score 0):

Humidity is the death of a piano.  I hope you're not talking about a grand piano.  Humidity can cause wood and leather to swell or soften, which could most definitely affect the feel, sound and action of the piano.

I very strongly recommend closing windows and running a de-humidifier.

Comment: Pianos are manufactured to suit the climate of the territory they are sold into. If you live in a predominantly humid area & dehumidify the air, you will do as much damage as vice versa.